# Slab Leak in Foundation

Tags: leak, slab

If there is a slab leak, will the water eventually come directly out of slab above the leak or can it come up in the surrounding are?

Comment: Is this from a pipe or ground water?   Ground water leak can be anywhere, usually weakest spot.  A pipe leak should be in the area of the pipe by a few feet.

Comment: You must determine where the leak is. If you have old copper pipes, then you must consider the posssibility of widespread corrosion for which a solution might be replumbing the house. But if you have newer copper or have plastic this might be an isolated leak which should be repaired at the point of failure. There are companies which specialize in locating leaks under a slab, but they can be wrong. A friend had a running toilet which one plumber thought was a leak under the slab.

Comment: please provide more specifics: what leak, where, pictures, other details about slab and situation: basement? inside/outside? rain? plumbing?

Answer (score 1):

From experience and logically, the water will travel around and find the most porous spot to come up.

We had a water leak under the concrete floor.  The plumber wanted to break up the concrete at that spot.  I told him to put a new line above the ground.  Because

1. The spot where the water is coming out is not a guarantee of the leak spot.
2. If it's broken in one spot, it will probably soon break in another spot, and then another.

If you have a leak from a water pipe, I would advise to put in a new pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Most slabs are constructed with a vapor barrier under the concrete pour. The plumbing is under that vapor barrier but, can come through the slab where needed. A leak under the vapor barrier often does not manifest itself through the slab, unless it is severe.

If water should get into the slab, it can be released at a spot or spots far from the source.

A neighbors condo had water seeping through the grout in the middle of the living room tile. The leak was from the upstairs neighbors bath which was on the other end of the unit, about 40 feet away.
If you are seeing water seeping up through your slab, the source can actually be the roof , (We actually had chimney caps leak) or upstairs plumbing.  Investigation is needed before breaking up your slab.